# How to make vb.net Modules work in a multithreaded environment

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, module, vb6, vb6-migration

I am working on a project that was converted from vb6 into vb.net,
The project is an IIS service, because of that it must work with multi-request/thread environment.

There is an issue of corrupted data that i think comes from the large use of Modules in that project.

I read that in vb6 each thread used to create its' own instance of the Module compared to vb.net where a Module is truly global, which can cause the data corruption.

My question is - is there a way to make the vb.net modules function in the way they used to work in vb6, or do i need to rethink and rewrite all the parts that are multithreded?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `vb6` but you might need to change all the modules into classes which allows you to create an instance of the "module".

Comment: I figured that, but before i invest time and effort i want to make sure there's no simpler way, it's a deprecated project, it's a waste to spent so much time on it :)

Comment: Modules are like global single instance classes, both in vb.net as well as in vb6. Are you sure you are hitting the correct target?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/383886-module-level-variables-multiple-threads-iis

Comment: "in vb6, module variables are created as thread local storage (really nothing
to do with apartment model)."